# How to disable Express BodyParser for file uploads (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, node.js-connect

I'm using Node.js + Express to build a web application, and I find the connect BodyParser that express exposes to be very useful in most cases. However, I would like to have more granular access to multipart form-data POSTS as they come - I need to pipe the input stream to another server, and want to avoid downloading the whole file first.

Because I'm using the Express BodyParser, however, all file uploads are parsed automatically and uploaded and available using "request.files" before they ever get to any of my functions.

Is there a way for me to disable the BodyParser for multipart formdata posts without disabling it for everything else?

Comment: Aaaarg! I've just spent over a day trying to figure out why I couldn't upload files when the sample app (without Express, but also, obviously, with many other differences too) worked perfectly. Turns out `bodyParser` is the culprit. Thanks for asking this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you type `app.use(express.bodyParser())`, almost each request will go through `bodyParser` functions (which one will be executed depends on `Content-Type` header).

By default, there are 3 headers supported (AFAIR). You could see sources to be sure. You can (re)define handlers for `Content-Type`s with something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = express.bodyParser;

// redefine handler for Content-Type: multipart/form-data
bodyParser.parse('multipart/form-data') = function(req, options, next) {
  // parse request body your way; example of such action:
  // https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/multipart.js

  // for your needs it will probably be this:
  next();
}
```

---

**upd.**

Things have changed in Express 3, so I'm sharing updated code from working project (should be `app.use`ed *before* `express.bodyParser()`):

```
var connectUtils = require('express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils');

/**
 * Parses body and puts it to `request.rawBody`.
 * @param  {Array|String} contentTypes Value(s) of Content-Type header for which
                                       parser will be applied.
 * @return {Function}                  Express Middleware
 */
module.exports = function(contentTypes) {
  contentTypes = Array.isArray(contentTypes) ? contentTypes
                                             : [contentTypes];
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (req._body)
      return next();

    req.body = req.body || {};

    if (!connectUtils.hasBody(req))
      return next();

    if (-1 === contentTypes.indexOf(req.header('content-type')))
      return next();

    req.setEncoding('utf8');  // Reconsider this line!
    req._body   = true;       // Mark as parsed for other body parsers.
    req.rawBody = '';

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
      req.rawBody += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', next);
  };
};
```

And some pseudo-code, regarding original question:

```
function disableParserForContentType(req, res, next) {
  if (req.contentType in options.contentTypes) {
    req._body = true;
    next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Or you can `delete express.bodyParser.parse['multipart/form-data'];` **before** `app.use(express.bodyParser())` as @jwerre suggested.

Answer (score 64):

If you need to use the functionality provided by `express.bodyParser` but you want to disable it for multipart/form-data, the trick is to not use `express.bodyParser directly`. `express.bodyParser` is a convenience method that wraps three other methods: `express.json`, `express.urlencoded`, and `express.multipart`.

So instead of saying

```
app.use(express.bodyParser())
```

you just need to say

```
app.use(express.json())
   .use(express.urlencoded())
```

This gives you all the benefits of the bodyparser for most data while allowing you to handle formdata uploads independently.

**Edit:** `json` and `urlencoded` are now no longer bundled with Express. They are provided by the separate [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) module and you now use them as follows:

```
bodyParser = require("body-parser")
app.use(bodyParser.json())
   .use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
```

Comment: Or you can define your own `bodyParser` for `multipart/form-data` Content-Type header: `require('express').bodyParser.parse['multipart/form-data'] = function yourHandler(req, options, next)...`

Comment: That's even better - if you submit that as an answer with a short code sample I'll make it the accepted answer for the thread. Remarkable how hard that simple piece of information was to find. Thanks!

Comment: This is really handy to know, especially for thinning out dependencies of mounted apps!

Answer (score 27):

If the need for body parsing depends only on the route itself, the simplest thing is to use `bodyParser` as a route middleware function on only the routes that need it rather than using it app-wide:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express.createServer();
app.post('/body', express.bodyParser(), function(req, res) {
    res.send(typeof(req.body), {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
});
app.post('/nobody', function(req, res) {
    res.send(typeof(req.body), {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
});
app.listen(2484);
```

Answer (score 15):

Within Express 3, you can pass parameter to the `bodyParser` as `{defer: true}` - which in term defers multipart processing and exposes the Formidable form object as req.form. Meaning your code can be:

```
...
app.use(express.bodyParser({defer: true}));

...
// your upload handling request 
app.post('/upload', function(req, res)) {
    var incomingForm = req.form  // it is Formidable form object

    incomingForm.on('error', function(err){

          console.log(error);  //handle the error

    })

    incomingForm.on('fileBegin', function(name, file){

         // do your things here when upload starts
    })


    incomingForm.on('end', function(){

         // do stuff after file upload
    });

    // Main entry for parsing the files
    // needed to start Formidables activity
    incomingForm.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){


    })
}
```

For more detailed formidable event handling refer to https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm not doing anything wrong, but event listeners wont work in my case. I've checked the source code of multipart.js and the middleware calls next after parsing whole data (and there's no possibility to call it twice), so event's are emitted before assignment in you example

Comment: It seems that Formidable is no longer included in Express 4. See https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/264

Answer (score 5):

I've faced similar problems in 3.1.1 and found (not so pretty IMO) solution:

to disable bodyParser for multipart/form-data:

```
var bodyParser = express.bodyParser();
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if(req.get('content-type').indexOf('multipart/form-data') === 0)return next();
    bodyParser(req,res,next);
});
```

and for parsing the content:

```
app.all('/:token?/:collection',function(req,res,next){
    if(req.get('content-type').indexOf('multipart/form-data') !== 0)return next();
    if(req.method != 'POST' && req.method != 'PUT')return next();
    //...use your custom code here
});
```

for example I'm using node-multiparty where the custom code should look like this:

```
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.on('file',function(name,file){
       //...per file event handling
    });     

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
       //...next();
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

With express v4, and body-parser v1.17 and above,
You can pass a function in the `type` of bodyParser.json.
body-parser will parse only those inputs where this function returns a truthy value.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    type: function(req) {
        return req.get('content-type').indexOf('multipart/form-data') !== 0;
    },
}));
```

In the above code,
the function returns a falsy value if the `content-type` is `multipart/form-data`.
So, it does not parse the data when the `content-type` is `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 1):

throw this is before app.configure

```
delete express.bodyParser.parse['multipart/form-data'];
```

Comment: I tried that at various parts in my code and it always made the app crash immediately.

Comment: Did you put it before you instantiated your bodyParser? If not you should do that.