# How can i controll file uploads on node.js & express 3.0 server

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

As you can see here:
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/multipart/index.js
Express support file uploads by default and store each uploaded file on the temp folder for later use.

My question is: **Is it safe?**

As I see it, an attacker can fill up all the temp folder with garbage files without any control on it.
Should i check each POST request and delete any unused file?

Comment: Here’s a similar question that may provide an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295554/how-to-disable-express-bodyparser-for-file-uploads-node-js

Comment: Thanks, I saw that. This solution disable all the file uploads from all requests. What I'm looking for is enable it only for few requests.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest two solutions to your problem.

1. Use a virtual drive for your upload location. If your server is running on linux, it is very easy to mount a virtual file system which is in memory only. The files will be placed here faster than if it was on a real harddrive, and if you have problems like the one you describe, it is only a matter of cleaning out the virtual drive or restarting the server. [Look at this article for an explaination of ram disks](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html).
2. Make sure that you only accept a maximum number of x uploads from the same ip address during during a 24 hour period. Combine this solution with solution 1 for maximum effect. One way of implementing this, is to have a global object with upload counts for each ip address, and then clear it out every 24 hours.

   ```
   var uploads = {}
   setInterval(function(){
    uploads = {}
   }, 24*60*60*1000); //Run every 24 hours

   var onUpload = function(request, file){
     if(uploads[req.ip] > maxUploadsAllowedPrUser)
       fs.unlink(file) //Delete the file
     else
       uploads[req.ip]++ //Keep the file, and increase count
   }
   ```