# AJAX call in expressJS

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I can't seem to get the AJAX call correct.  There have been other QA that deal with the `$.ajax()` function but I'm trying to solve this with `$.post()`.

When the form button is clicked the javascript at the head is executed, which includes a `$.post()`.  The url `/login` is routed through and passed to `loginPost` function.  There a response is determined and sent back to the javascript (right?).  Instead, webpage renders the response (pass || fail).

Why isn't the response from the AJAX call being sent back to get processed?

This is a simple example that I am working with to get me better acquainted to how AJAX in expressJS and jQuery work.  Any Help is greatly appreciated!

--**views/login.jade**

```
script(src='/_js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')
script
  $(document).ready(function(req, res) {
    $('#login').submit(function() {
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    $.post('/login', formdata, processData).error('ouch');

    function processData(data, status) {
      console.log(status);
      console.log(data);
      if (data == 'pass') {
        $('#content').html('<p>You have successfully loggin in!</p>');
      } else {
        if (! $('#fail').length) {
          $('#formFrame').prepend('<p id="fail">Incorrect login information. Please try again)</p>');
        }
      }
    } //end processData
  }); //end submit
}); //end ready

div.main
h1= title
div#formFrame
  form(id='login', action='/login', method='POST')
p
  label(for='username') Username:
  input(id='username', type='text', name='username')
p
  label(for='password') Password:
  input(id='password', type='password', name='password')
p
  input(id='button', type='submit', name='button', value='Submit')
```

--**routes/index.js**

```
app.post('/login', loginPost);
```

--**routes/loginPost**

```
module.exports.loginPost = function(req, res) {
    var password = 'admin'
      , username = 'user'
      , data = req.body;

    if (data.username == username && data.password == password) {
      res.send('pass');
    } else {
      res.send('fail');
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the response to `/login` when you call it outside a browser in something like curl, i.e. `curl -X POST -d "username=blah&password=blah" <host>/login`?

Comment: username=asdf&password=asdf&button=Submit --> the response is `fail`

Comment: Are you including either a [`urlencoded`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/urlencoded.html) or [`bodyParser`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html) in the `app`'s configuration?

Comment: I have the bodyParser but not the urlencoded.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295554/how-to-disable-express-bodyparser-for-file-uploads-node-js) says bodyParser 'wraps three other methods - express.json, express.urlencoded and express.multipart.'  Do you think I would need to explicitly state it?

Comment: @user1460015 No. You should only need one or the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You still have to stop the `<form>` from submitting via its default action, which can be done with [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
$('#login').submit(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // ...
});
```

Otherwise, the `<form>` will redirect the page to its `action` (or back to the current address if no `action` was given), interrupting the `$.post` request.

Comment: That did it.  Preventing the default action correctly sent the response from the AJAX request to the processData function.