# How to send file received through api to google drive nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, multer

I am new to Nodejs and trying to send file received through multer to google drive. However I am setting

```
var media = {
               mimeType: req.file.mimetype,
               body:req.file
            };
```

Which is giving me error as

[image]

```
const index = require('../index.js');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

let drive = google.drive('v3');
const receive = multer();

router.post("/insertNewProduct", auth, receive.single('productUrl'), async (req, res) => {
    try { 
        
                const data = req.body;
                var folderId = '1v3tdYH_GLtCOOxhQ8HXDdRAb-2Jh455_';
                let fs = require('fs')
                var fileMetadata = {
                    'name': new Date().toISOString()+req.file.filename,
                    parents: [folderId]
                };
                var media = {
                    mimeType: req.file.mimetype,
                    body:req.file
                };
                drive.files.create({
                    auth: index.jwtClient,
                    resource: fileMetadata,
                    publishAuto: true,
                    media: media,
                    fields: 'id'
                },
                 async function (err, file) {
                        if (err) {
                            // Handle error
                            console.error(err);
                        }
                        else {

                            console.log('********File create success. File Id: ', file.data.id);
                            res.status(201).send({
                                message: "Record Create Successfully",
                                data: newRows
                            });
                       }

                    }
                      );
              }  
        }
   
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Inside catch: " + e);
        res.status(404).send({
            message: e,
            data: {}
        });
    }
});
```

As I understand the error, how I set the `body:req.file` is wrong.
Here's how `req.file` look like.

[image]

How can I pass req.file to

```
 var media = {
                    mimeType: req.file.mimetype,
                    body:req.file
                };
```

I tried `body:req.file.buffer` but it didn't work.

Comment: So the req.file.buffer is typeof object but it is expected to be instance of Buffer or URL or typeof string.

Comment: a quick search, looks like you want to be passing in a stream not a buffer, possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851466/express-fileupload-to-google-drive-api

Comment: you should show the full error and stacktrace not a picture of one line

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved the issue using the link you have provided.