# Using formidable with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, formidable

I'm creating an app in node.js using express. My app needs to allow users to upload pdf files. I got the upload working with [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) but I was reading the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable#installation) it states the following:

> This is a low level package, and if you're using a high level framework such as Express, chances are it's already included in it

I tried reading the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295554/how-to-disable-express-bodyparser-for-file-uploads-node-js) that the documentation referred to, but being new to node.js and express, I don't quite understand.

Doing a bit of research I found that you can use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) with express, but after messing around with it (and being very new to node) I couldn't get it to work how I got my app to work with formidable.

Is there any issue with using formidable with express? The documentation seemed to think there would be easier ways.

Comment: Do you resolve? I found this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable