# How to disable restify.plugin.bodyParser for file uploads

Tags: node.js, restify

This question is very similar to [How to disable Express BodyParser for file uploads (Node.js).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295554/how-to-disable-express-bodyparser-for-file-uploads-node-js) But the answer they have provided is for Express and I have tried the solution with the Restify 7, and it does not seem to work.

I'm using Node.js + Restify to build Restfull application. I am using BodyParser,to parse post parameters. However, I would like to have access to multipart form-data POSTS.

I use multer, multer-s3 and aws-sdk and I want to have access to the data to send them to digitalocean sapce. But all file uploads are parsed automatically by restify.plugin.bodyParser.

Is there a way for me to disable the BodyParser for multipart formdata posts without disabling it for everything else?

This is an example code :

```js
const restify = require('restify');
const errors = require('restify-errors');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

const server = restify.createServer();

server.use(restify.plugins.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());

// Set S3 endpoint to DigitalOcean Spaces
const spacesEndpoint = new aws.Endpoint('nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com');

const s3 = new aws.S3({
  endpoint: spacesEndpoint
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'space_name',
    acl: 'public-read',
    key: function (request, file, cb) {
      console.log(file);
      cb(null,new Date().toISOString());
    }
  })
}).single('logo');

server.post('/upload', async (req, res, next) => {
        upload(req, res, async (error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return next(new errors.InvalidContentError(error));
          }
          console.log('File uploaded successfully.');
          res.send(200);
          next();
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed `server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());` by `server.use(restify.plugins.jsonBodyParser());` and everything is working fine